# CLLocationCoordinate2D error when running in Simulator Swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, maps

I keep getting this error when I run my project in the simulator. It only occurs in the xcode simulator. When i run the project on my phone it seems to work perfectly.

Here's my code:

```
extension QuadTreeNode: AnnotationsContainer {

@discardableResult
func add(_ annotation: MKAnnotation) -> Bool {
    guard rect.contains(annotation.coordinate) else { return false }

    switch type {
    case .leaf:
        annotations.append(annotation)
        // if the max capacity was reached, become an internal node
        if annotations.count == QuadTreeNode.maxPointCapacity {
            subdivide()
        }
    case .internal(let children):
        // pass the point to one of the children
        for child in children where child.add(annotation) {
            return true
        }

        fatalError("rect.contains evaluted to true, but none of the children added the annotation")
    }
    return true
}

@discardableResult
func remove(_ annotation: MKAnnotation) -> Bool {
    guard rect.contains(annotation.coordinate) else { return false }

    _ = annotations.map { $0.coordinate }.index(of: annotation.coordinate).map { annotations.remove(at: $0) }

    switch type {
    case .leaf: break
    case .internal(let children):
        // pass the point to one of the children
        for child in children where child.remove(annotation) {
            return true
        }

        fatalError("rect.contains evaluted to true, but none of the children removed the annotation")
    }
    return true
}

private func subdivide() {
    switch type {
    case .leaf:
        type = .internal(children: Children(parentNode: self))
    case .internal:
        preconditionFailure("Calling subdivide on an internal node")
    }
}

func annotations(in rect: MKMapRect) -> [MKAnnotation] {

    // if the node's rect and the given rect don't intersect, return an empty array,
    // because there can't be any points that lie the node's (or its children's) rect and
    // in the given rect
    guard self.rect.intersects(rect) else { return [] }

    var result = [MKAnnotation]()

    // collect the node's points that lie in the rect
    for annotation in annotations where rect.contains(annotation.coordinate) {
        result.append(annotation)
    }

    switch type {
    case .leaf: break
    case .internal(let children):
        // recursively add children's points that lie in the rect
        for childNode in children {
            result.append(contentsOf: childNode.annotations(in: rect))
        }
    }

    return result
}
}
```

The error seems to happen when this line is invoked in the code:

```
    _ = annotations.map { $0.coordinate }.index(of: annotation.coordinate).map { annotations.remove(at: $0) }
```

The error that I get reads: Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of:CLLocationCoodinate2D)'

Not sure why I get this error only in the simulator.

Comment: I honestly don't know, but can the simulator use CoreLocation? I'd think maybe not.

Comment: Yes, you can simulate location using Xcode. The weird thing is, that seems like a compile time error message to me and not the description of a runtime error...

Comment: It shouldn't work on your phone or the simulator since `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s aren't `Equatable`

Answer (score 0):

In this

```
_ = annotations.map { $0.coordinate }.index(of: annotation.coordinate)
```

What annotations contain?. I guess `annotations.map { $0.coordinate }` is not returning an array of  `CLLocationCoodinate2D` for some reason. 
Because the error says that.

assign something like

```
coordinates = annotations.map { $0.coordinate }
```

And you will realise that coordinates is not an array of `CLLocationCoodinate2D` thats why you are not allowed to call index(of : ) on this array.

Comment: I believe my code is correct and fine. It runs perfectly on my iphone but for some reason it does not run on my simulator on my laptop. Any reason why that might be?

Comment: From the error message I can guess that only. Can you please define coordinates the way I have done and check what it is getting. I am sure that its not getting an array of CLLocationCoodinate2D. Can you please let me know the type of annotations? What annotations contain here.